# RegEx: how to remove a word in greater than sign and less than sings?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a sentence:

```
'hi how <unk> are you'
```

I need to remove `<unk>` from it.

Here is my code:

```
re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format('<unk>'), '', 'agent transcript str <unk> with chunks for key phrases')
```

Why doesn't my RegEx work for <...>?

Comment: There is no word boundary between a space an `<` or `>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no word boundary between a space an `<` or `>`, you could instead try

```
re.sub(r'(\s*)<unk>(\s*)', r'\1\2', your_string)
```

Or - if you don't want two spaces, you may try

```
re.sub(r'(\s*)<unk>\s+', r'\1', your_string)
```

---

Remember that `\b` is a word boundary between a non-word character (`[^\w+]+`)  and a word character (`\w+` or `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).  In your original string, you were trying to find a boundary between a space and a `<` or `>` where `\b` is not matching.

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FKGqs4/1).

Comment: The `r'(\s*)<unk>(\s*)'` is a wrong solution. The right one: `r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape('<unk>'))` or `r'(?<!\S){}(?!\S)'.format(re.escape('<unk>'))`

Comment: May I know is there any difference between  ​re.sub(r'<unk>', '', 'hi how <unk> are you') and you RegEx?

Comment: @illuminates You want to search for whole words, thus, you need unambiguous word boundaries. Or whitespace boundaries. Or custom boundaries, just you must come up with your definition of a "word".